# Redundant Explicit Array Creation in argument of 'params' parameter is not correct for indexer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

In the following example code (which is not supposed to do anything other than illustrate my question):

```
public class Example
{
  private void ExampleMethod()
  {
    this[new string[0]] = "something";
  }

  public string this[params string[] stuff]
  {
    get { return null; }
    set { stuff[0] = ""; }
  }
}
```

ReSharper prompts me with the warning:

> Redundant Explicit Array Creation in argument of 'params' parameter.

This would be correct in the case of a method that had params, but in the case of an indexer the array creation is not redundant. Resharper’s ‘fix’ changes this to the following, which won’t compile:

```
this[] = "something"; // Won't compile
```

It makes sense to me that an indexer requires a parameter, so is this a bug in ReSharper, or am I missing something?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. You can always `// Resharper disable once` it.

Comment: Formally, you are correct. But an indexer acepting 0 parameters could also be called a design error. It is very dodgy, at the least. I hope R# won't  make too much allowances for this extreme corner case.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree that it could be a design error, but C# allows it, so I should be allowed to do it. I don’t think Resharper should introduce compiler errors.

Comment: It introduces a Warning, not an Error. That seems proper, even if you enable "Warnigs as Errors". Just don't this 'feature'. Add constraints for `stuff.Length>0` intead.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It does introduce an error. The code won’t compile after Resharper has ‘fixed’ it. The issue I have is that our Resharper code cleanup settings will automatically apply this rule. We could disable that setting, but that would ignore the 99% of cases that we _do_ want to fix.

Comment: But why do you have `foo[] = bar;` in the first place?  That just shouldn't come up.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don’t have `foo[] = bar`. I have `foo[new string[0]] = bar`. Resharper _changes that_ to `foo[] = bar`, which then won’t compile. I agree with you that this code is unusual, and perhaps it’s not even good, but it _is_ allowed, and the question is not about whether this is sensible code, it’s about whether Resharper should introduce code that does not compile.

Comment: Well, `foo[new string[0]] == foo[]`. But you're right, it seems to be a R# bug. Just not a big one.

Comment: I am getting the same Resharper warning in this code --- actualOutput = actualOutput.TrimEnd(new char[] {'\r', '\n'});

Comment: @mmesser314 - and how does resharper rewrite that?

Comment: One correction it will do is  TrimEnd(new char[] {'\r', '\n'}) -> TrimEnd(new[] {'\r', '\n'}). Another is -> TrimEnd('\r', '\n') from a different warning on the same code. Both compile, both are correct. I guess the point is the feature has a valid use and code where it works correctly.

Comment: @mmesser314 I agree, but the specific warning I’m talking about is “Redundant explicit array creation in argument of ‘params’ parameter” (which also has a valid use and code where it works correctly). Are you sure this is the exact warning you’re getting?

Comment: I will raise this with ReSharper as soon as I can, and post it as an answer. Hopefully they can resolve this. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a bug, and I have raised it as such with JetBrains. The particular request is [here](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/1098296), although annoyingly, it seems that you have to log in to be able to view it.

I will therefore post any updates here.

(EDIT: I've found that you can also raise it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466518) and this is publicly visible.)

The general feeling seems to be that having params in an indexer is unwise. I would tend to agree. Personally, I've never come across a need to do so, and it does feel odd to me, but that doesn't mean that there's no use case for it.

In my case, I didn't write the code, and changing it is not currently an option. If you find yourself in the same situation, the easiest thing to do, as already mentioned, is to select "Disable once with comment" on the warning. It will then be ignored by future cleanups.